# How to select a winning records based on a priority field

Tags: sql

I have a table that has the following columns:

`eID`(`PK`), `memberID`(`PK`), `eName`, `priority`, `qualified`

There can be multiple records for a particular `eID`, `memberID` combination but each with a different priority, so something like this

```
1234, jsmith, news,         1, NULL
2345, jsmith, reactivation, 2, NULL
```

I need to write a query that will evaluate the rows in the table and assign the qualified column based on the priority, so the results would be

```
1234, jsmith, news,         1, Y
2345, jsmith, reactivation, 2, N
```

So to complicate matters my table will have rows added to it through out the day and each time a new set of data is added to it I will need to rerun the prioritization query.

An annoying note, I cannot use cursors, variables or temp tables to do this. I can create supporting tables and copy data to them on a temporary basis but they would be physical tables.

Any help would be appreciated. If my description of the problem sucks, I apologize, let me know how I can be more explanatory and I will do my best.

thanks

Comment: I think you need to describe how priorities are distributed per eid/memberid combination and how the winning record is selected. It sounds like a trigger running a update query could work. Also, please add a tag for the specific database management system you are using (preferably with version).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I think this SQL will give you what you want

```
UPDATE MyTable SET qualified='N'
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyTable.qualified = 'Y'
FROM MyTable
INNER JOIN (select memberID, MIN([priority]) as [priority] FROM MyTable GROUP BY memberID) T2
ON T2.memberID=MyTable.memberID AND T2.priority = MyTable.priority
```

Give it a shot and see if I have understood the requirements correctly

Answer (score 0):

Taking unqualified as the name of your base table, I'd create a view on top.

The advantage of a view in your case is that you don't have to recompute qualified entries as new member/priority records get added, so the result is always "live".

You could have an already_processed_flag on the underlying table and add logic on the view to handle that.

```
create view qualified_view
(eid, memberId, ename, priority, qualified)
as 
select eid, memberId, ename, priority, 'Y' as qualified

from unqualified
where not exists 
/* is there anything @ higher priority? */

(select 1 from unqualified s
where s.memberId = unqualified.memberId
where s.eid <> unqualified.eid and s.priority > unqualified.priority
)

union

select eid, memberId, ename, priority, 'N' as qualified

from unqualified
where exists 
(select 1 from unqualified s
where s.memberId = unqualified.memberId
where s.eid <> unqualified.eid and s.priority > unqualified.priority
)
```

Now the union is there to handle both the case where there is something more urgent and if there is not, not knowing which database you are aiming for.

In Oracle for example, you might use NVL, like this instead (syntax errors are possible, doing this freehand):

```
create view qualified_view
(eid, memberId, ename, priority, qualified)
as 
    select eid, memberId, ename, priority,
NVL((select 'Y' from unqualified s
where s.memberId = unqualified.memberId
where s.eid <> unqualified.eid and s.priority > unqualified.priority
limit 1
),'N') as qualified
from unqualified
```

MS SQLServer has a rough equivalent to NVL, isNull.  Other RDBMS may or may not have something similar.